# Logging the return value of a function

Tags: c++, logging

I would like to log the return value of a function. The problem is that the function might have many exit points and I don't want to add a log call before every one of them.

I thought about having an inner object that's responsible on making the `Log` call. But still, I would have to notify it about the return value before each `return` statement.

I also thought about creating a macro that calls the logger before returning from the function. Something like:

```
#define RETURN(ret) Logger.log(__FUNCTION__, ret); return ret;
```

But I want to avoid doing that.

Any other thoughts on how I can achieve that nicely and easily?

Thanks

Comment: why not let the caller log the return value?

Comment: The function is exported from a DLL. I would like the DLL to log all API calls.

Comment: @user If it's MSVC there is an automatic way of doing this, but it is definitively not nice and easy (instead it's naughty and hard). It's possible to generate a DLL that wraps the other and intercepts all calls.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do that more nicely and easily. In this case I think the solution with least impact on the source is to use the preprocessor, but you shouldn't do it the way you do because it has surprices built in. Fx:

```
if( done )
    RETURN(something);
```

expands to:

```
if( done )
    Logger.log("function_name", something); return something;
```

which means that `something` is sent to the log if `done` is true, then `something` is returned anyway.

To make the expansion fit into a single statement it's normally wrapped in a `do { ... } while(0)` which would make that example log and return only if `done` is true.

But there's still a surprise since the macro argument is expanded twice, consider the case where you write `RETURN(something++);` then it will expand to `Logger.log(__FUNCTION__, something++); return something++;` which means unfortunate side effects. This was a real problem in C, but not in C++. Here templates are handy:

```
 template<typename T>
 T const& log_and_return(char const* func, const T& value)
 {
      Logger.log(func, value);
      return value;
 }

 #define RETURN(value) return log_and_return(__func__, value)
```

Note that it is called `__func__` in the standard (an **not** `__FUNCTION__`).

Comment: Just a note, but `__func__` is not actually a macro, but a variable.